# K8s default network policy, deny or allow?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

My system contains network policies, and I have a doubt about one of them.
I can't test it. I just can print out the config and 'imagine' what it does.

```
kubectl get networkpolicies
=>   
...
spec:
    ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
    podSelector: {}
    policyTypes:
    - Ingress
```

I'm not sure if the one above denies all traffic from other namespaces, or on the contrary allow all traffic.

from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/ chapter 'Default policies' I would say it allows all traffic, but I'm not quite sure ...

The 'describe' does not really help me:

```
kubectl describe networkpolicies
=>
...
Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    From:
      PodSelector: <none>
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

What do you think ?
Thanks!

Comment: why dont you test it by trying to make some requests?

Comment: Why do you expect random folks over the internet to run this test for you? Why cant you test this ? Seems trivial.

Comment: I can't test it. I just can print out the config and 'imagine' what it does.

Comment: Please don't include the command use to generate a yaml, it messes up the formatting and makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The following netpol would allow all Ingress traffic:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

This would deny all Egress & Ingress traffic:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Comment: OK but it does not answer my question... The policy I printed out has one 'ingress' section compare to your deny policy, and has 'from : podSelector: {}' in the 'ingress' section compare to your allow policy. This is what makes me doubting.

Comment: I'm not sure what's there not to understand. Yours allows all ingress.

Comment: My doubt is : in K8s official page (link in my description), default-allow-all policy have " ingress: - {}". In my policy, this is "ingress:  - from:  - podSelector: {}". I'm not sure how it changes the behavior. All right, so you confirm what I though, it allows all ingress. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK I got your point now: as empty curly bracket { } selects everything, "- from:       - podSelector: {}" means all pods are selected. Then it makes a allow-all-policy. 
I'm just annoyed how the 'describe' interprets it : "PodSelector: <none>". I would have found logical if it were something like " <any> (traffic allowed from all pods)" ...